# SAPUI5 XML View text not visible

Tags: xml, view, model, sapui5

i am new to SAPUI5 and got a problem with displaying the contents of my model.

For example, i am setting a model with following JSON:

```
var a = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
  name: 'testtttt',
  test : [ {
    val : 1
  }, {
    val : 2
  } ],
  test2: [1,2,3,4]
});

a.setDefaultBindingMode("OneWay");

this.setModel(a, 'test');
```

Now, in the XML View i am trying to display it via Listitem:

```
    <List items="{test>/test}">
        <items>
            <StandardListItem title="{val}" description="{val}"></StandardListItem>
        </items>
    </List>
```

The result are two lines of blank Listitems without content

[image]

Any ideas :( ?

Comment: This is a common mistake quite some people make: you should specify the used model in your `StandardListItem` bindings as well, as @herrlock just pointed out

Comment: Also, test>/test seems a bit off - is the > supposed to be there? (No experience with SAPUI5, but I do know some XML, and this looks like a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the StandardListItem to use the `test`-model:

```
<List items="{test>/test}">
    <items>
        <StandardListItem title="{test>val}" description="{test>val}"></StandardListItem>
    </items>
</List>
```